# Find the points of continuity

Tags: continuity, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Take a function defined by

\begin{cases}
0 & x\in \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \mathbb{Q}\\
\sin|x| & x\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
Find the points of continuity.

By solving $\sin|x|=0$, I get $x=n\pi$, where $n\in \Bbb N $,
  but $\pi$ is irrational.

So how do I find the points of continuity?

Comment: @MichaelHardy The OP is confused. Which answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that points of continuity exists when the limit at the $x$-value exists and  a point is defined on that $x$-value.

So inorder for

\begin{cases}
0 & x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\
\sin|x| & x\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}

to have continuous points at $x=n\pi$, $\underset{x\in\mathbb{R/Q}}{\lim\limits_{x\to n\pi}}0=\underset{x\in\mathbb{Q}}{\lim\limits_{x\to n\pi}}\sin|x|$
and $\sin|n\pi|=0$

In real analysis textbooks a limit that is restricted to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ may exist as long as the subset is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. This is because such a subset can "closely approximate any real value" 
or in formal terms every real number is a limit point of that subset. Hence you must prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Then we can say

$$\underset{x\in\mathbb{R\setminus Q}}{\lim\limits_{x\to n\pi}}0=\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}}{\lim\limits_{x\to n\pi}}0=0$$

and

$$\underset{x\in\mathbb{ Q}}{\lim\limits_{x\to n\pi}}\sin|x|=\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}}{\lim\limits_{x\to n\pi}}\sin|x|=0$$

Hence

$$\underset{x\in\mathbb{R \setminus Q}}{\lim\limits_{x\to n\pi}} 0 = \underset{x\in\mathbb{Q}}{\lim_{x\to n\pi}} \sin|x|$$

Finally since $\sin(n\pi)=0$ we know that all continous points are at $x=n\pi$.

Comment: Why the above ans is wrong? These are the two concepts,  which make dogs and cats in me. But which is the proper ans? I cant understand.